# Can't make javascript run correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle, checked

I have a jsfiddle, but I cannot make the javascript run correctly. The fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/davidm1181/suW6f/.

The javascript code that is stopping it is the following:

```
if ($(this).checked()) {
    $('.r1').val('true');
}
```

The problem is, that I have the same code running on my production web server and it works fine, and on my web server if I change checked() to just checked the code will still run, but it will always return true. Can somebody please help me understand this? Thank you.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to reflect the correct way of doing this Thank you again John S and all the others that have posted answers for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Explanation of your results:**

There is no `.checked()` function for a jquery object. Therefore, when you call `$(this).checked()`, it results in the following error being thrown:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'checked'.
```

Also, there is no `checked` property for a jquery object.  Therefore, the value of `$(this).checked` is `undefined`, which is considered falsy. (You say it always returns true, but I think that is a mistake.)

**Correct way to check if a checkbox is checked:**

You can use any one of the following:

```
if (this.checked) {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
```

Which one you use is a matter of style.

Answer (score 1):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/suW6f/3/)***

Use

```
if(this.checked) or if($(this).is(':checked'))
```

instead of

```
if ($(this).checked()) {
```

Code:

```
$(':checkbox').change(function () {
    $('.r1').val(this.checked);
    $('.r2').val(this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have to validate if a checkbox is checked I use is(':checked'):

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.r1').val('true');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing called .checked() in jquery or javascript

you can use

1. `.checked` - use with `this` only
2. `.is(":checked")` - use with `$(this)`
3. `.prop("checked")` - use with `$(this)`

I have generated a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/suW6f/2/)